# Increase tag on each loop javascript

Tags: javascript, imacros

I know it has been asked a few times, but none of them works for me, because i have if statements:

```
if(s != "#EANF#") {
    iimPlay(macro2);
}

if(s == "#EANF#") {
    iimPlay(macro1);
}
```

Basically i need a variable that increases every time when macro1 run, but it should not take an effect on which macro will be played.

Comment: Please clarify what "it should not take an effect on which macro will be played" means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var myNum = 0;

if (s == "#EANF#") {
    iimPlay(macro1);
    myNum++;
} else {
    iimPlay(macro2);
}
```

By declaring a variable outside your functions it can be manipulated by either function.

Comment: I feel like this should work, although ...I'm curious what code leads to the given snippet. Obviously if this is all inside an onClick, then myNum will become 0 each time, and it should go even further outside.